# What metrics can be fetched from metrics-server for Horizontal Pod Autoscaling

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, horizontal-scaling

I am working on a use case related to Horizontal Pod Autoscaling. I am able to fetch memory and CPU usage from the metrics server in order to decide on scale out (found this after reading multiple blogs).

I wish to know if any of the other standard metrics such as throughput, disk usage, resource consumption etc. can be fetched from the metrics server. Have not been able to find anything on the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all available metrics from [Documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/tree/master/Documentation) of kube-state-metrics for all available resources.

Also, as mentioned in [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) you can use custom metrics

> The Horizontal Pod Autoscaler automatically scales the number of pods
>   in a replication controller, deployment or replica set based on
>   observed CPU utilization (or, with [custom metrics](https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/custom-metrics-api.md) support, on some
>   other application-provided metrics). Note that Horizontal Pod
>   Autoscaling does not apply to objects that can’t be scaled, for
>   example, DaemonSets.